# Maximum length of about me in stackexchange api?

Tags: stackexchange, stackexchange-api

What is the Maximum length of "about me" in stackexchange api?

The one from here: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/me?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow`

And in general, where are the length limits published? If anywhere?

Comment: Might be better on http://stackapps.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on stackapps

Comment: See: [A\[n\] \[In\]complete Character-Limiting Guide to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372184/435726)